# Error deploying a pod in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, yaml

I'm trying to deploy this yaml in my kubernetes cluster into one of my nodes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-1
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

But when I try to deploy it with the command, I get this error message

```
pi@k8s-master-rasp4:~ $ kubectl apply -f despliegue-nginx.yaml -l kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-worker-1
error: no objects passed to apply
```

Anyone knows where the problem could be?

Thanks

Comment: what if you just do `kubectl apply -f despliegue-nginx.yaml`? I don't think `-l` is required here.

Comment: also, does your file `despliegue-nginx.yaml` contain the above yaml definition? `error: no objects passed to apply` is observed when you pass an empty object in `kubectl apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to use label selector (`-l`) with `kubectl apply...`.

Use [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) to assign pods to specific nodes:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-1
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: k8s-worker-1 # <-- updated here!
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```